# How to Fetch Last 10 database Transaction In IBM DB2..?

Tags: java, db2

I would like to fetch last 10 database transaction in IBM DB2..
Means Which Last 10 transaction execute In DB2..

Comment: What exactly do you do want to get? The dml directly with values? you can eventually get the executed statements. If they are dynamic you won't get values. And you can get them, even if they have not been commited.

Comment: transaction log might be of use to you

Comment: I want : For Ex : In My Project user perform lots of action , In database there are lots Query Are fire when performing an action so i want at least last 10 operation that which last 10 Query are fire...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need that for, you will have to set up the [DB2 audit facility](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005483.html) or use an [activity event monitor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/c0053163.html).

Answer (score 0):

> SQL tables have no implicit ordering, the order has to come from the
>   data. Perhaps you should add a field to your table (e.g. an int
>   counter) and re-import the data.

If you cannot do so, then here is one more idea which is coming to my mind, while writing this answer. Can we use rownum to get the last 10 records? Perhaps yes, here is what you can try, i am just throwing this idea and have not tested.

- Get the MAX(rownum) from the table
- Fetch the records from the table between the max(rownum) to max(rownum) -10

Aghh sounds ugly but see if it works for u.

Btw if you don't know about rowid then here is link to learn about that:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0052875.html

Answer (score 0):

If there is a column in your table that you can use to ascertain the correct order, such h as a transaction number or a value generated by a sequence reference, or some column(s) that you can use to ORDER BY, then simply add DESCENDING after each column in the ORDER BY clause,  and FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS.